# Weak or strong property declaration when returning value of related view?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, properties, strong-references

I read a Stack Overflow answer that compared `strong` properties on an object to leashes on a dog. For every declaration made with a strong reference, a new leash is added to the dog. Once every person walking the dog goes home (or once every object with a strong reference deallocates), the dog (the allocated memory), can be freed. I think that's how it went. I apologize to the original poster if I totally butchered that. Anyway, here's my situation. I have an `NSDocument` subclass that has a property called `backgroundColor`. Here's what my `NSDocument` subclass is doing accessor-/mutator-wise:

```
- (NSColor *)backgroundColor
{
    return self.window.backgroundColor;
}

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    self.window.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

So, my document object doesn't actually own the "leash," but at the same time, it's important for that dog to keep walking, or the document won't have a background color. Now I think I'm just confusing myself with the metaphor. At the end of the day, I just want to know whether to declare "forwarded" properties as being `strong` or `weak`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare it as a property. Providing the getter and setter implementations as you have is enough. A property doesn't help you here because there is no value to store.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. The more I overthink things, the more I overlook them. I do have a follow-up question though; is KVC/KVO/binding still available without a property?

Comment: According to http://www.objc.io/issue-7/key-value-coding-and-observing.html, yes you can.

Comment: Damn, you're fast! Well played, sir. Thank you. P.S. That objc.io is amazing in terms of each article's depth. Wowza.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have your own setter and getter and you don't use the property ivar, `strong` or `weak` doesn't have any importance. The ivar is never read or assigned.

I would probably go with `strong` because `[UIWindow backgroundColor]` is `strong` but `weak` will work exactly the same.

Comment: I believe `retain` is the default, which in ARC is functionally-equivalent to `strong`.